# android:draw line on your device and show it to another device though wifi with no delay

Tags: android

My goal is to develop an android app that can share screen with another device with no delay.

If I draw an line on my device, I hope another device get the same line.

I just need some suggest.
I have some questions.

1. dose the android api support these feature?(drawing line on anther device.)
2. if it dose, which package can do the trick.
3. if it dose not , it seems that I need to write my own api, isn't it?

thanks,
charlie.

Comment: What you're asking is too broad, especially for your apparent programming knowledge. Step 1: focus on learning how to use the Canvas first. In other words, focus on learning how to make a drawing application for one device. That small amount of functionality is difficult enough for a beginner.  Step 2: Then try your hand at doing an asynchronous drawing application, in which you draw something, you serialize it, you upload it somewhere, someone else downloads it, renders the drawing, and draws on top of it. That too is not trivial. Step 3: Research WifiDirect, or Bluetooth DNLA, or TCP sockets

Comment: Each of these three technologies have their own limitations and tradeoffs to take into account. My advice is. Don't even try to go down that road yet. Focus on just completing Step 1. That itself is not going to be easy. And please come back when you've done some research and you've tried out some code to get to that Step 1. The example code you'll find will be incomplete and barebones. You'll have to refine that code to make that drawing application even halfway useable for a normal person to use and you'll also need to refine that code to gain mastery and understanding over its functionality

Comment: yeah. your answer is exactly what I want. Thank you, I'll have try. Hope to keep contacting you on stack overflow.